# Loading models in THREEjs SEA3D

Tags: javascript, graphics, 3d

I am using the mascot turtle in THREEjs examples, using the sea3d loader.How to save the object in a variable to update its x and y positions?
I have tried to load it in a variable morph by storing object in an array and try to access it from array arr in the render function but that does not seem to work.

```
   loader.load( './models/sea3d/mascot.tjs.sea',function(err,result){
            mesh= result.object;
            mesh.position.set(0,0,0);
            scene.add(mesh);
            arr.push(mesh);


         });


        render(){
           var morph=arr[0];
           morph.position.x+=5;
           renderer.render(scene,camera);
      }
```